# Add log4net to C# code generated dynamically

Tags: c#, log4net, codedom

We have code that gets compiled into a library using CodeDom.
In some of these classes I would like to add log4net statements.

I am not sure about the syntax to add the following line (so that I can use the log object for logs later in the class) into the code that will be compiled dynamically :

```
 private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

So far I have the following in the class that builds the code:

```
//create log4net entry
        CodeMemberField log4netField = new CodeMemberField(typeof(log4net.ILog), "log");
        log4netField.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Static | MemberAttributes.Private;
```

Should I then use InitExpression? As in:

```
log4netField.InitExpression = new CodePrimitiveExpression();
```

I can't seem to find how to assign a value to a field as part of the declaration, and I also don't find how I can state it as readonly.

This has been of some help: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404245%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but it doesn't have examples of everything that I need.

So, my main problem is how to add this:

```
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

I do not know a lot about CodeDom, but I suspect something might not work if I add it as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare the following in a method that returns `ILog` in your core components:

```
 return LogManager.GetLogger(new StackTrace().GetFrames()[1].GetMethod().DeclaringType);
```

And then obtain an instance thereof in the code that gets dynamically compiled like so:

`var log = Log.Get();`

That way, regardless of whether your code is dynamically compiled in via the CodeDom or was in there from the start, you'll always end up with a logging instance for the calling type without having to use Reflection.

I've been using this implementation throughout my code for almost a year now, and even projects that use dynamically compiled plugins can handle logging this way without any noticeable side effects.