# log4net and multiple start-up projects in solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, log4net

We have many projects in the solution, and quite a few projects that act as test projects for certain of the class library projects.
Project Vis and Project Test can both act as start-up projects, or Project Test can be started as a separate process from out of Project Vis. They both focus on a class library Project Calc.
So, if I test Project Calc with Project Test then log4net works fine. However, if I use Project Vis (which is a Visual Studio addin still in VS2010) as the start-up, and then launch Project Test to test Project Calc, I hit problems.

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This is thrown from the Constructor for a class in Project Calc.

With a slightly different internal configuration for code in Project Calc in which we use CodeDom to build some C# files and to compile it into a seperate dll that Project C uses (look at the aevitas answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767975/add-log4net-to-c-sharp-code-generated-dynamically)), I have received:

> System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
>   Message: The type initializer for 'Test' threw an exception.

I think this is also related to the log4net implementation.

I have links to the external log4net config file in all the projects, and the following line once in each project:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4NetSettingsGlobal.xml", Watch = true)]
```

and the following line once in each class from whence I call the log methods:

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

So could the problem be because of having Project Vis already configured with log4net and then starting Project T?
How could I work around this, so that I can accommodate both scenario's? (That is, Project T also being executed on its own to test Project Calc.)

Comment: Are you sure that this problem is related to multiple start programs? We are using this scenario with log4net for years now...We've had a problem that was related to the fact that the same library was loaded with different versions as part of an add-in and as part of the project being used.

Comment: The first error regarding the assembly I get when I have log4net added to Project Calc, and then run the Test Project from out of the Visual Studio addin. The second error regarding the TypeInitialization I get when I don't have log4net added to Project Calc, but still run the Test Project from out of the Visual Studio Addin. I do not get any errors if I remove log4net from all three the projects. I also do not get any errors of I just run the Test Project as the start-up, apart from the Visual Studio Addin.

Comment: However, I see now that the log calls in the Visual Studio Addin does not work. Should I rather configure log4net programmatically in the Addin? How would/could this affect the configuration of the Test project when run from out of the Addin?

Comment: Managed to get the log calls to work in the Addin, by not having a assembly reference, but by calling `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo("C:\\Log4NetSettingsGlobal.xml"));`
Still getting the above-mentioned errors though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your log4net dll is not copied to your bin directory. Check if the dll is there and if not configure your project to copy it to your bin directory. You can easily test this by copying the log4net dll by hand into your bin directory when running as addin.

Comment: No, the log4net.dll gets copied.

Comment: Or should I say, the log4net.dll gets copied to the bin directory, but since Project Test's exe is in a different directory, I had to copy the log4net.dll there as well. So you are right.

Comment: However, I still don't get the logs to work from Project Test and Project Calc when run from out of Project Vis, even though I don't have the above runtime errors any more.